# Unity - Camera ScreenToWorldPoint returning odd values

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The main camera's output is set to a render texture, which is applied to a material, which is applied to a quad that's scaled up to 128x72. The secondary camera is set to only see what is rendered to the child quad, who has the material with the render texture on it.

However `Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition)` is returning values that aren't even close to the `GameObject`. I.E. The `GameObject` is instantiated at `(0, 0, 0)`, and hovering over it shows the mouse at `(307, 174)`. Moving the `Rotating Object` to the right edge of the screen will only return an x position of 64 (half of the 128px wide quad) so I'm not sure where the 300+ is coming from. Not sure if the quad/camera set up is responsible for this.

**EDIT:** Using a single orthographic camera, all properties the same except for using a render texture, instead of the setup I have now results in accurate `ScreenToWorldPoint` output.

[image]
[image][image][image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your entire hierarchy window?

Comment: This question was posted twice. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50135097/unity-camera-screentoworldpoint-returning-odd-values/50137210#50137210

Comment: @Immorality - The first image is the entire hierarchy window. I'm only testing this with the camera (and children) and the rotating object.

Comment: Does the rotating object contain a collider/trigger?

Answer (score 2):

The `Input.mousePosition` property will only return the x and y axis of the mouse position in pixels.

`ScreenToWorldPoint` requires the z axis too which `Input.mousePosition` doesn't provide. The z-axis value supposed to be the [`nearClipPlane`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-nearClipPlane.html) of the camera. It will give you a position that's right in front of the camera.

Depending on the size of the 3D object you want to instantiate where mouse button is pressed, you will need to apply an offset to it to make it totally visible to the screen. For a simple cube created in Unity, an offset of `2` is fine. Anything bigger than that, you will need to increase the offset.

Below is a complete example of how to properly use `ScreenToWorldPoint` with `Camera.nearClipPlane` and an `offset` to instantiate a 3D object where mouse is clicked:

```
public GameObject prefab;
public float offset = 2f;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Camera cam = Camera.main;

        Vector2 mousePos = Vector3.zero;

        mousePos.x = Input.mousePosition.x;
        mousePos.y = Input.mousePosition.y;

        Vector3 worldPoint = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(mousePos.x, mousePos.y, cam.nearClipPlane + offset));

        Instantiate(prefab, worldPoint, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, as with the comment above, changing the z distance does nothing to change the values output from ScreenToWorldPoint.

Comment: Can you edit your question with your new current code ?

Comment: I have no code updates. However, I have another idea that might help so i've updated the question.

Comment: @EvanWard When people provide answer and it didn't help, instead of replying with "nothing changes" or "it does not work", Edit your question and add a new code you are using after reading the answer. Without that it's not possible to tell what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Apologies. I did try both examples provided as written as well as trying to change some values/references, though since the outcome was the same in every situation I figured simply showing the code provided was unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

You may not be calling the `Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint` method correctly. In particular, the z position of the screen position parameter that's passed to this method should be defined as world units from the camera. See the [Unity documentation on Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html).

Instead of `Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition)`, I think this is the correct way to call `Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint`:

```
var cameraPosition = Camera.main.transform.position;

// assuming `transform` is the transform "Virtual Screen Quad"...
float zWorldDistanceFromCamera = transform.position.z - cameraPosition.z;

var screenPoint = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, zWorldDistanceFromCamera);
var worldPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPoint);

Debug.LogFormat("mousePosition: {0} | zWorldDistanceFromCamera: {1} | worldPoint: {2}",
                Input.mousePosition,
                zWorldDistanceFromCamera,
                worldPoint.ToString("F3"));
```

(If this isn't working, could you update your question or reply to this post with a comment with details showing the values that are logged at each step?)

Comment: Adjusting the z distance changes nothing in the values logged. I even set up a slider to manually test varying z distances. A z value of -10 ends up logging the same values as a z value of 10 and everything in between.

Comment: Hmm, could you post a screenshot of your hierarchy window for the single orthographic camera example that is working? As well as the associated code and the logged output at each step? That could help viewers narrow down the problem by comparing your problem vs the single camera case.

Comment: Also, you say that "hovering over it shows the mouse at (307, 174)", but that you're not sure where the 300+ is coming from. Note that the mouse position is in screen coordinates, and `Input.mousePosition` returns a value as follows "The bottom-left of the screen or window is at (0, 0). The top-right of the screen or window is at (Screen.width, Screen.height)." [Source: Unity Input.mousePosition documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-mousePosition.html). So the right of your screen may correspond to 64 for your Rotating Object, but for your mouse it's `Screen.width`.

Answer (score 1):

I was just struggling with this problem and this question helped me find the answer, so thank you for posting it!

The issue has nothing to do with the z axis or how you're calling `Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint`. The issue is that the camera you're calling it on is rendering to a RenderTexture, and the dimensions of the RT don't match the dimensions of your game window. I wasn't able to find the implementation of the method in the [reference source](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/search?q%3Dscreentoworldpoint%26unscoped_q%3Dscreentoworldpoint&sa=D&source=hangouts&ust=1587214584314000&usg=AFQjCNHZcv29WPkhEngfu_zmYZVyM9RIow), but whatever it's doing is dependent on the resolution of the RenderTexture.

To test this, click the `stats` button in the game window to display the game window's screen size. The coordinates you get will match the ratio between that and the RenderTexture resolution.

**Solutions:**

1. Don't call this method on a camera targeting a rendertexture, either target the screen (none) or create a child camera that matches the position of the camera you need
2. Match the RT resolution to the screen. Obviously this may have performance implications, or cause issues if the screen size changes.
3. Don't use `Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint`. Depending on the use case, using a raycast may be simpler or more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Since using a default camera was returning the correct values, I simply added another one to detect the mouse position independent of the render texture/quad setup.