# Screen Point to World Point Touch Positions Conversion

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am working on basketball shooting game and something like this kind of environment setup I have.
[image]

Within the "swipe area" player is swiping his finger to shoot the basketball. Finger swipe data, I was getting in pixels using Input.mousePosition and I have to convert these pixels data into Unity units for shooting basketball logic.
But pixels to unity units conversion not working properly, I mean, there was a problem in screen point to world point conversion.

For finger touch down, I have written this code:

```
touchPos = new Vector3( Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, cameraForShooter.nearClipPlane);
touchDownWorldPos = cameraForShooter.ScreenToWorldPoint(touchPos);
Debug.Log("touch down mouse pos: " + touchPos + " world pos: " + touchDownWorldPos);
```

For finger touch up, I have written this code:

```
Vector3 screenPoint = Input.mousePosition;
screenPoint.z = targetZ;
Vector3 worldPoint = cameraForShooter.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPoint);
Debug.Log("touch up mouse pos: " + screenPoint + " world pos: " + worldPoint);
```

And this kind of Console output I have when I run the project:
[image]

As you are seeing in the above image, for touch down I don't have correct conversion for Screen Point to World Point. I don't know why this is happening.

Because of this, the basketball was not shooting in the correct direction.
Please suggest me something for this.

**EDIT:**

After doing some research, I have changed my code like this way:

Touch Down Code:

```
touchPos = Input.mousePosition;
touchPos.z = targetZ;
touchDownWorldPos = cameraForShooter.ScreenToWorldPoint(touchPos);
touchDownWorldPos.z = cameraForShooter.nearClipPlane;

Debug.Log("touch down mouse pos: " + touchPos + " world pos: " + touchDownWorldPos);
```

Touch Up Code:

```
Vector3 screenPoint = Input.mousePosition;
screenPoint.z = targetZ;
Vector3 worldPoint = cameraForShooter.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPoint);

Debug.Log("touch up mouse pos: " + screenPoint + " world pos: " + worldPoint);
```

This is video recording so you can understand how it performing now:
[Basketball Shooting Recording Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uPU1wMuI77IhCbeOPnbrzcYz3r6JmZTJ/view?usp=sharing)

If you notice extreme left or right side I can't able to shoot the ball.
Just within center area its working properly I can say, 30 degree left and right sides.

Please suggest me next changes after this progress.

Comment: why do you use different z values for your vector?

Comment: what is targetZ?

Comment: Basically I want to do finger swipe on touch area box and shoot the basketball in the swiped direction - this is my motto. What Z value shall I use? I can't able to understand this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unity - Camera ScreenToWorldPoint returning odd values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50135097/unity-camera-screentoworldpoint-returning-odd-values)

Comment: @SoroushHosseinpour Thank you sir, let me go through them one by one and reply back to you here :)

Comment: @SoroushHosseinpour Above reference not helped me because I required to calculate two points, touch start and touch end so that I can calculate direction for the shooting.

Comment: Please check edited section of the question.

Comment: does putting absolute values like vector3.left yields desired results?

Comment: But where to place Vector3.left?

Comment: I think you add force to your basketball gameobject, and you get its direction based on user input, ignore the user input vector and replace it with Vector3.left

Comment: No no, this will not work for me - I need user accurate shooting. Gimmick will not get approved :)

Comment: just for testing, I want to see if the problem is the from input system or other parts of your code.

Comment: Please someone suggest me - please check EDIT section of my question for most latest progress.

Answer (score 0):

Coverting screen position to world position is possible by using ScreenToWorldPoint method, as explained in Unity [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html) for input:

> A screen space position (often mouse x, y), plus a z position for depth (for example, a camera clipping plane).

```
// Since you are using UI elements, you can use IPointerDownHandler and IPointerUpHandler
public class Answer : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler
{
    private Camera _cam;

    private void Start()
    {
        _cam = Camera.main;
    }
    
    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        print(UI2World(eventData.position));
    }

    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        print(UI2World(eventData.position));
    }

    private Vector3 UI2World(Vector2 mousePosition)
    {
        return _cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(mousePosition.x, mousePosition.y, _cam.nearClipPlane));
    }
}
```

Comment: ScreenToWorldPoint() method x value is dependent on z value. If we provide same z value to touch start and touch end point then x value is coming almost identical. There is no difference in left or right swipe.

Comment: PointerEventData.position is a vector2. there is no z value.

Comment: _cam.nearClipPlane - z value we are applying through this line so for both touch start and touch end points we are applying same z value so relatively the same x value we are getting

Comment: converting mouse position to world position is done using cameraNearClip for the z value of ScreenToWorldPoint. If you want to apply force in z direction you have to transform your vector

Comment: you can read the document to gain more insight about your problem